# Prevent deleting or updating the parent if child exists in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

```
declare @parent table
(
    [SEARCHID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [COMPID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [COMPPNO] [varchar](35) NOT NULL,
    [PACKSIZE] [varchar](100) NOT NULL
)

DECLARE @CHILD TABLE
(
    [SEARCHID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [COMP_ID] [int] NULL,
    [PROD_LINK] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [SRPNO] [varchar](24) NULL
)
```

May anyone please help me? How can I assure if searchid present in child then it should not changed or deleted in parent table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you really needing this with a declared table variable? In this case you need to use local logic.

If you define your tables physically, either as temp table or as table within one of your databases, you'd solve this easily with a foreign key constraint:

Try it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE parent
(
    [SEARCHID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [COMPID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [COMPPNO] [varchar](35) NOT NULL,
    [PACKSIZE] [varchar](100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE CHILD
(
    [SEARCHID] [int] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FK_Child_SearchId FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES parent(SEARCHID),
    [COMP_ID] [int] NULL,
    [PROD_LINK] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [SRPNO] [varchar](24) NULL
)
```

#### EDIT: Did not see the *should not change*

If your parent row should not change **at all** if there is at least one child, you'd read about `INSTEAD OF TRIGGER` to enforce your wanted behavior.